# How do i get the value from a callback in Nodje.js / Javascript, to access the value of a response to a query, using mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Okay, so first time asking a question here...
I've been trying to access a MySQL database with Node.js
But i've run into a problem, when i try to get the result back from a query.
i have tried:

```
let response = await con.query(q, async (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        return err
    } else {
        return result
    }
});
```

this returns a "Query" Object from the mysql module itself... not the error or the result how do i acces these, what am i missing?

Comment: Got same issue, finally use callbacks or promises to handle that.

Comment: Can't  make a snippet now (using phone). Just make a function that takes a callback and that callback will take the result or the error.

Comment: Or make a function  that returns a promise and pass your code inside... if there is result you  solve the result else you reject thz error

Answer (score 0):

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/

Use a catch of the query Promise to respond to errors gracefully.